# I want to make a roulette loop by Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I want to make a roulette by Arduino UNO R3. I want the loop to stop and sound from the speaker when the switch is pressed when pin 9 is HIGH. I want all the LEDs to light up at that time

```
void setup(){
  for(int i=5;i<14;i++){
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);       //LEDOin(5~13)
  }
  pinMode(1,INPUT);         //switch
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);        //speaker
}

void loop(){
  int i;
  while(true){
    for(i=5;i<14;i++){
      digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(i,LOW);
      delay(500);
  }

  if(digitalRead(1)==HIGH){
     break;
  }
 }
 if(digitalRead(9)==HIGH){           //success
    for(i=5;i<14;i++){
      digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
      tone(2,261,100);
      tone(2,261,100);
      delay(1000);
    }
 }
 else{                               //fail
   for(i=5;i<14;i++){
     digitalWrite(i,LOW);
     delay(1000);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please be more precise in asking questions, Tell us what error you are facing, and what was expected result.

Comment: first of all forger about the `delay` function

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you change the part of your code regarding success is enough, this link below may have content that can help you.
[click here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/189289/)